# Why I can't add value to second chart?

Tags: c#, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm currently using MS Chart Control. And in this object i have 2 series: Balance and Volume. Data to

```
foreach (double balance in grStats.getChangedBalance())
{
    chartBalanceAndVolume.Series["Balance"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, balance));
}
```

added succesfully. But if i write as

```
int index = 1;
foreach (double volume in grStats.getVolumes())
{
    chartBalanceAndVolume.Series["Volume"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(index, volume));
    index++;
}
```

this leads to the addition of the values ​​in the chart "Balance". Why is that?

Comment: Not sure as what you mean the X value would show all of them in this case i guess starting from 0 to index (whatever the number of records are there)

Comment: Each chart can contain several series, all of which are drawn in the same chart area. Is that what you are seeing? Did you want it drawn in a separate chart area?

Comment: @V4Vendetta No, the problem is not there.Especially checked this "defect"

Comment: @MatthewWatson I want to draw two charts at one place

Comment: @MatthewWatson Divide into 2 parts of my main chart get a similar result

Comment: Both Series are probalby sitting in the same ChartArea. Without knowing more, like the ChartType we cn't know..